# MEL script do...while endless loop

Tags: mel

I create an endless loop with this code:

```
int $a = 1;
int $b = 2;
int $c = 10;
do  {
        if(($a + $b) < $c){
            print ($a + $b);
            $a++;
            } 
    }
while($a < $c);
```

Do anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:
I'm guessing the problem had to do with scope. So removed the brackets.
https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-MEL-handles-scope.html

```
int $a = 1;
int $b = 2;
int $c = 10;

do {
    if (($a + $b) < $c)
        print ($a + $b);
        $a++;
}
while ($a < $c);
```

Alternative syntax:

```
int $a = 1;
int $b = 2;
int $c = 10;

for ($a; $a < $c; $a++)
{
    if (($a + $b) < $c)
    {
        print ($a + $b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used at least also a for loop.